# thedevdojo/chatter SQLSTATE[HY000] foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to install a [Chatter forums](https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter) on my Laravel application. When I reach the `php artisan migrate` stage, I receive this error:

> Migrating: 2016_07_29_171118_create_chatter_categories_table
>   Migrated:  2016_07_29_171118_create_chatter_categories_table
>   Migrating: 2016_07_29_171118_create_chatter_discussion_table
>   Migrated:  2016_07_29_171118_create_chatter_discussion_table
>   Migrating: 2016_07_29_171118_create_chatter_post_table
>   Migrated:  2016_07_29_171118_create_chatter_post_table
>   Migrating: 2016_07_29_171128_create_foreign_keys
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `chatter_discussion` add constraint `chatter_discussion_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
>
> at /var/www/laravel/exoscape/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664

I have searched around and it seems that Laravel 5.8+ uses `BigInteger` by default and this package does not support that.

Is there any way I can fix this? I have done a rollback after receiving this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('txs', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id')->autoIncrement();
       $table->integer('donor_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('donor_id')->references('id')->on('patients');
       $table->integer('recipient_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('recipient_id')->references('id')->on('patients');
       $table->timestamps();
   });
}
```